# input output error in accessing any of the folders?

Tags: centos

I don't understand why I am getting input output error when accessing the home directory, downloads directory, or any other directory for the user `msingh`, `msingh` is my login account for my system.

I tried login in as root and I see everything as fine I was able to traverse into the home, downloads folder for the user `msingh` from the root user.

I belive the reason is my failing disk , right now i am logged in as root since loggin in as msingh gives problems:

[image]

dmesg output :

```
[ 2310.776265] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 159993664 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2310.776280] ata5: EH complete
[ 2381.510891] STATE_INVALID_DROP: IN=enp41s0f3u2 OUT= MAC=d2:7c:5d:bd:1c:b4:36:c0:18:43:00:7f:86:dd:62:86:08:13:00:14:06:37:20:01:4d:e0:ac:19:00:00:00:00:00:01:00:0b:00:2a:24:09:40:43:21:86:03:2f:26:ea:56:59:58:62:d8:4a:01:bb:b8:12 SRC=2001:4de0:ac19:0000:0000:0001:000b:002a DST=2409:4043:2186:032f:26ea:5659:5862:d84a LEN=60 TC=40 HOPLIMIT=55 FLOWLBL=395283 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=47122 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
[ 2604.967339] STATE_INVALID_DROP: IN=enp41s0f3u2 OUT= MAC=d2:7c:5d:bd:1c:b4:36:c0:18:43:00:7f:86:dd:62:89:9f:6a:00:14:06:37:20:01:4d:e0:ac:19:00:00:00:00:00:01:00:0b:00:3b:24:09:40:43:21:86:03:2f:26:ea:56:59:58:62:d8:4a:01:bb:ed:32 SRC=2001:4de0:ac19:0000:0000:0001:000b:003b DST=2409:4043:2186:032f:26ea:5659:5862:d84a LEN=60 TC=40 HOPLIMIT=55 FLOWLBL=630634 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60722 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
[ 2642.639149] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x380 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2642.639152] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 2642.639154] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2642.639158] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:38:40:4f:89/00:00:09:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 41/40:08:40:4f:89/00:00:09:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2642.639159] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2642.639160] ata5.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2642.900832] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 2642.900856] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=2s
[ 2642.900858] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 2642.900859] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2642.900862] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 09 89 4f 40 00 00 08 00
[ 2642.900865] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 159993664 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2642.900891] ata5: EH complete
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Is thee anything specific or unusual with your system? Does the problem occur since you created the user? Or did it work before? Did you change anything? Please add details about the file system in which your home directory is locaed.

Comment: it was working fine ultill yesterday, a sudden powerloss and i am facing this after powering it back on

Comment: The output of `dmesg` may give you more clues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments. What exactly do you do "when accessing the home directory" as user `msingh` or as `root`? What command or program do you use? Please copy&paste the complete error message. Please show the output of `df -k /home/msingh` and `awk 'NR==FNR {fs=$NF;next} $2==fs' <(df -k /home/msingh) /proc/mounts`. For these commands I assumed that `/home/msingh` is your home directory. Otherwise replace this in both commands as necessary.